# Should displaying an unsigned char* & an signed char* output exactly the same result

Tags: c++

I am unsure if I am correctly translating/converting a `unsigned char*` to a regular `signed char*`?

The `unsigned char*` is a string that has been hashed. Does the following code correctly convert an `unsigned char*` to `signed char*`?

```
std::string message = "to be encrypted";
unsigned char hashMessage[SHA256_DIGEST_SIZE];

SHA256::getInstance()->digest( message, hashMessage );

// is this conversion correct
char* hashMessageSigned = reinterpret_cast<char*>(hashMessage); 
printf("Unsigned Char Hash: %s\n", hashMessageSigned);  //  The 2 printf's print out exactly the same strings is that correct?
printf("Signed Char Hash: %s\n", hashMessage);
```

Comment: What does the documentation of whichever library you're using say digest() does ? (likely it returns a binary representation of the hash value, you should convert it to something printable, e.g. a hex string, before printing it )

Comment: and what exactly is the C part of your question ?

Comment: There's noting "regular" about signed char. Types `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three different, distinctive and independent types. Type `char` is not necessarily signed.

Comment: This code is not C. Removed the C tag.

Answer (score 4):

You're not converting anything here. Both `printf`s are instructed to treat the data as printable strings.

Signed or unsigned is a matter of interpretation. 0xFF can be 255 or -1, depending on how you interpret that. The "sign" of the type is the instruction that helps the compiler to interpret the data.

But in this case you don't treat the data as numbers at all, you treat it as strings, and then the interpretation is totally different: 0xFF is the character at the place 255 of the ASCII table. There's no sign there.

Just to be sure you got it: `reinterpret_cast<char*>` doesn't convert the data, it converts the way the compiler treats the pointer. The `%s` instructs how the `printf` should treat the pointer, and is unrelated to what the compiler was instructed to do before (and is done during run time).

Comment: There's no ASCII character at position 255.